# Argument 'fooController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm doing a web page and everything works great. No errors at all.

But now I decided to make a unit test case using Karma and Jasmine.

Somehow I get this error when I run my test

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'moduleApp.SearchPageController' is not a function, got undefined
```

I also tried just `SearchPageController` but I get the same error.

What is missing here??

```
Route

    angular.module('moduleApp').config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider
    .when('/cmt/complaint/search', {
        templateUrl: 'src/callCenter/page1/searchPage.html',
        controller: 'moduleApp.SearchPageController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

}]);
```

Unit test

```
 describe('Controller: SearchPageController', function () {

 var vm;

 beforeEach(module('moduleApp'));
 beforeEach(inject(function ($controller) {
     vm = $controller('moduleApp.SearchPageController', {}, {});
 }));

 it('should bla bla', function () {

    expect(vm).toBeDefined(); // vm is undefined, probably because of the erro above

 });
```

});

Controller

```
    angular.module('moduleApp.controller').controller('moduleApp.SearchPageController', SearchPageController);
SearchPageController.$inject = ['$log', '$scope', 'moduleApp.SearchPageService', '$http'];


function SearchPageController($log, $scope, searchPageService, $http) {
    'use strict';

    var vm = this;
    vm.filterOption = 'Account ID';

   }
```

Karma Config:

```
// Karma configuration
m

odule.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        'angular.js' // yes this is on the same folder, it works
        '../app/app.js',
        '../components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'unit/*.js',
        '..app/src/'
    ],


    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_LOG,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
    })
   }
```

Comment: if not even the master minds from StackOverflow can help me, who can.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely **don't** want to reference the controller with the module name:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/cmt/complaint/search', {
    templateUrl: 'src/callCenter/page1/searchPage.html',
    controller: 'moduleApp.SearchPageController', //<--- this is never correct
    controllerAs: 'vm'
})
```

You always access a controller, service, or factory by the name it was defined:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/cmt/complaint/search', {
    templateUrl: 'src/callCenter/page1/searchPage.html',
    controller: 'SearchPageController',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
})
```

It looks like you are including your tests BEFORE you include your app source:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    'angular.js' // yes this is on the same folder, it works
    '../app/app.js',
    '../components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'unit/*.js',
    '..app/src/' //<-- if this is your app source, it should be before tests!
],
```

I would just re-arrange the last two entries, but it also looks like you aren't actually including any files with the `'..app/src/'` statement. You should use the wildcarad to include all `.js` files:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    'angular.js' // yes this is on the same folder, it works
    '../app/app.js',
    '../components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    '..app/src/**/*.js' //<--- all .js files in folders and subfolders
    'unit/*.js',
],
```

Typically, you want your tests to be the very last entry in the files section of your config.